# Spring JPA using @Lock Annotation with Postgres Backend LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is enforcing no wait

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA @Lock annotation to acquire row level lock in Postgres. I need to use `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` which tries to acquire Postgres lock with no wait option (fails with error immediately in case lock is held by some other thread). Is it possible to change this behaviour where the thread waits for the lock instead of failing immediately?

To add some more context, default behaviour for `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` is to wait for lock. I can provide it hint to fail immediately as well if needed using query hint. But I am unable to configure this for `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` which by default fails immediately.

````
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "0")})
Optional<TessellServiceJpaEntity> findById(UUID id);```
````

Answer (score 1):

**Short story**

You need to implement your own `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` which won't add `nowait` to select statement and pass that dialect to HBN via `hibernate.dialect` property.

**Long story**

First of all, JPA specification does not specify how JPA provider should acquire `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` lock, and at the first glance HBN behaviour seems to be reasonable:

*if there is other competing transaction which has acquired `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` lock, our transaction will eventually fail because when competing transaction increments version stamp our data becomes stale, so, there is no reason to wait for competing transaction to complete and we may fail lock request immediately.*

Unfortunately such behaviour misses two other obvious cases:

- competing transaction may hold shared (read) locks, so, we should not fail in that case
- our transaction may not contain data yet: we just want to retrieve fresh data and simultaneously  place a lock on it

So, that is definitely short-sight of HBN team.

Now, the question is whether it possible to overcome this undesired behaviour from HBN using `spring-data` API? My first idea was to write two repository methods like:

```java
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Entity findWithWriteLockById(long id);

@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
Entity findWithForceIncrementById(long id);
```

and call those methods successively: at first we acquire `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` and then we upgrade it to `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`

The problem is this approach does not work with HBN because `spring-data` implements such methods via query api and there seems to be a bug in `org.hibernate.loader.Loader#instanceAlreadyLoaded` [method](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4bf9bfac5a9589d4cbd0bdfd49a2dcd0c526fe70/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.java#L1703) - it does not schedule increment of version stamp (in case of HBN `v6` it does not properly upgrade locks too, however the method is different):

```java
if ( LockMode.NONE != requestedLockMode && upgradeLocks() ) {
    final EntityEntry entry = session.getPersistenceContextInternal().getEntry( object );
    if ( entry.getLockMode().lessThan( requestedLockMode ) ) {
        //we only check the version when _upgrading_ lock modes
        if ( persister.isVersioned() ) {
            checkVersion( i, persister, key.getIdentifier(), object, rs, session );
        }
        //we need to upgrade the lock mode to the mode requested
        
        // !!!
        // !!! there should be something more conceptual
        // !!! like entry.forceLocked( object, nextVersion );
        // !!!
        entry.setLockMode( requestedLockMode );
    }
}
```

---

UPD. For HBN `v5.4` implementation of custom dialect would look like:

```java
public class PostgreSQL10CustomDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {

    @Override
    public String getForUpdateString(LockOptions lockOptions) {
        switch (lockOptions.getLockMode()) {
            case PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT:
                return getWriteLockString(lockOptions.getTimeOut());
            default:
                return super.getForUpdateString(lockOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getForUpdateString(LockMode lockMode) {
        switch (lockMode) {
            case PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT:
                // not clear what default strategy is better
                // return getWriteLockString(LockOptions.NO_WAIT);
                return getWriteLockString(LockOptions.WAIT_FOREVER);
            default:
                return super.getForUpdateString(lockMode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getForUpdateString(String aliases, LockOptions lockOptions) {
        switch (getLockMode(aliases, lockOptions)) {
            case PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT:
                return getWriteLockString(aliases, lockOptions.getTimeOut());
            default:
                return super.getForUpdateString(aliases, lockOptions);
        }
    }

    protected LockMode getLockMode(String aliases, LockOptions lockOptions) {
        if (aliases != null && aliases.isEmpty()) {
            LockMode lockMode = lockOptions.getLockMode();
            final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, LockMode>> itr = lockOptions.getAliasLockIterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                // seek the highest lock mode
                final Map.Entry<String, LockMode> entry = itr.next();
                final LockMode lm = entry.getValue();
                if (lm.greaterThan(lockMode)) {
                    aliases = entry.getKey();
                }
            }
        }

        LockMode lockMode = lockOptions.getAliasSpecificLockMode(aliases);
        if (lockMode == null) {
            lockMode = lockOptions.getLockMode();
        }

        return lockMode;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, a couple of things though 1) Is there any good blog/documentation on implementation of Dialects that you can suggest 2)  there is other competing transaction which has acquired PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT lock, our transaction will eventually fail => This I don't get. If I wait right, there are two possibilities, either I will timeout since other transaction is still running or I will get the lock after some time (other transaction would have completed) and I would get the latest data. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 1. That would be helpful if you provided some inputs: HBN version, target DB. 
2. That is not about DB’s transactions, but about JPA specification, which is actually buggy: the behaviour depends on whether you have seen the data to be locked or not, unfortunately the pattern like “let lock something and then fetch actual state” is not covered (actually discouraged) by JPA

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the problem now. I think now we just need a good alternative solution to complete the answer. I have already mentioned the DB - postgres, Hibernate version I am currently on is 5.4.  Please edit your answer to provide a good reference to dialect implementation and I can accept it. Really appreciate your insights here.